# Apache traffic server minimum config return 404

Tags: reverse-proxy, http-proxy, apache-traffic-server

I am following the instruction mentioned in https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/9.1.x/getting-started/index.en.html#final-configurations

I created files as below

**records.config**

```
$ sudo cat /etc/trafficserver/records.config
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.http INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.reverse_proxy.enabled INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.pristine_host_hdr INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 8080 8080:ipv6
```

*We have another service running on port `443` and `80`, I cant run ATS on any of this ports.*

**remap.config**

```
$ sudo cat /etc/trafficserver/remap.config
map http://subdomain.domain.com http://127.0.0.1:80
```

I dont want to configure ssl or others for now, and didnt touch other files which are there and default.

When I try to make `curl` on port `8080`, it can see the headers and others, but it return `404`.

```
$ curl http://subdomain.domain.com:8080/api/v1/resource/id -ivk
* About to connect() to subdomain.domain.com port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 2001:4998:24:4::7000...
* Connected to subdomain.domain.com (2001:4998:24:4::7000) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/v1/resource/id HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: subdomain.domain.com:8080
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found on Accelerator
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found on Accelerator
< Date: Thu, 18 May 2023 22:37:24 GMT
Date: Thu, 18 May 2023 22:37:24 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Server: ATS/9.2.0
Server: ATS/9.2.0
< Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Language: en
Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 297
Content-Length: 297

<
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Not Found on Accelerator</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<H1>Not Found on Accelerator</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Your request on the specified host was not found.
Check the location and try again.
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>
* Connection #0 to host subdomain.domain.com left intact
```

I can see the `DEBUG` logs for `traffic_manager` in `/var/log/messages`

```
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.993] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <ProtocolProbeSessionAccept.cc:187 (mainEvent)> (http) probe needs data, read..
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSessionAccept.cc:49 (accept)> (http_seq) [HttpSessionAccept:mainEvent 0x2b63c801ec40] accepted connection from 2001:4998:24:4::7000:50134 transport type = 1
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <Http1ClientSession.cc:191 (new_connection)> (http_cs) [1] session born, netvc 0x2b63c801ec40
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <Http1ClientSession.cc:430 (release)> (http_cs) [1] data already in buffer, starting new transaction
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.h:174 (PostDataBuffers)> (http_redirect) [PostDataBuffers::PostDataBuffers]
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <ProxyTransaction.cc:51 (new_transaction)> (http_txn) [1] Starting transaction 1 using sm [1]
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:2730 (main_handler)> (http) [1] VC_EVENT_READ_READY/TS_EVENT_VCONN_READ_READY, 100
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:686 (state_read_client_request_header)> (http) [1] [&HttpSM::state_read_client_request_header, VC_EVENT_READ_READY/TS_EVENT_VCONN_READ_READY]
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:842 (state_read_client_request_header)> (http) [1] done parsing client request header
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:5543 (set_client_request_state)> (http_trans) [1] set req cont length to -1
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1360 (ModifyRequest)> (http_trans) [1] START HttpTransact::ModifyRequest
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1434 (ModifyRequest)> (http_trans) [1] END HttpTransact::ModifyRequest
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1436 (ModifyRequest)> (http_trans) Next action SM_ACTION_API_READ_REQUEST_HDR; HttpTransact::StartRemapRequest
May 18 23:17:09 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:7539 (call_transact_and_set_next_state)> (http) [1] State Transition: SM_ACTION_UNDEFINED -> SM_ACTION_API_READ_REQUEST_HDR
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:971 (StartRemapRequest)> (http_trans) [1] START HttpTransact::StartRemapRequest
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:991 (StartRemapRequest)> (http_trans) [1] Before Remapping:
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HdrHeap.cc:55 (obj_describe)> (http) HTTP_HEADER 0x2b632e821888: [T: 3, L:   48, OBJFLAGS: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HTTP.cc:550 (http_hdr_describe)> (http) [TYPE: REQ, V: 10001, URL: 0x2b632e821b08, METHOD: "GET", METHOD_LEN: 3, FIELDS: 0x2b632e8218b8]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HdrHeap.cc:55 (obj_describe)> (http) URL 0x2b632e821b08: [T: 2, L:  112, OBJFLAGS: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1723 (url_describe)> (http) [URLTYPE: 1, SWKSIDX: 99,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1725 (url_describe)> (http) #011SCHEME: "http", SCHEME_LEN: 4,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1726 (url_describe)> (http) #011USER: "", USER_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1728 (url_describe)> (http) #011PASSWORD: "", PASSWORD_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1729 (url_describe)> (http) #011HOST: "", HOST_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1731 (url_describe)> (http) #011PORT: "", PORT_LEN: 0, PORT_NUM: 0
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1732 (url_describe)> (http) #011PATH: "api/v1/resource/id", PATH_LEN: 38,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1734 (url_describe)> (http) #011PARAMS: "", PARAMS_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1736 (url_describe)> (http) #011QUERY: "", QUERY_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1738 (url_describe)> (http) #011FRAGMENT: "", FRAGMENT_LEN: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HdrHeap.cc:55 (obj_describe)> (http) MIME_HEADER 0x2b632e8218b8: [T: 4, L:  592, OBJFLAGS: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2632 (mime_hdr_describe)> (http) #011[PBITS: 0x0008000001000001, SLACC: 0xFFFFFFF2FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0FFFF, HEADBLK: 0x2b632e8218f8, TAILBLK: 0x2b632e8218f8]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2637 (mime_hdr_describe)> (http) #011[CBITS: 0x00000000, T_MAXAGE: 0, T_SMAXAGE: 0, T_MAXSTALE: 0, T_MINFRESH: 0, PNO$: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HdrHeap.cc:55 (obj_describe)> (http) FIELD_BLOCK 0x2b632e8218f8: [T: 5, L:  528, OBJFLAGS: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2653 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) [FREETOP: 3, NEXTBLK: (nil)]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2657 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) #011SLOT # 0 (0x2b632e821908), LIVE
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2666 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) [N: "User-Agent", N_LEN: 10, N_IDX: 64,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2667 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) V: "curl/7.29.0", V_LEN: 11,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2669 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) NEXTDUP: (nil), RAW: 1, RAWLEN: 25, F: 1]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2672 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http)
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2657 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) #011SLOT # 1 (0x2b632e821928), LIVE
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2666 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) [N: "Host", N_LEN: 4, N_IDX: 30,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2667 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) V: "subdomain.domain.com:8080", V_LEN: 36,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2669 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) NEXTDUP: (nil), RAW: 1, RAWLEN: 44, F: 1]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2672 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http)
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2657 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) #011SLOT # 2 (0x2b632e821948), LIVE
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2666 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) [N: "Accept", N_LEN: 6, N_IDX: 4,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2667 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) V: "*/*", V_LEN: 3,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2669 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) NEXTDUP: (nil), RAW: 1, RAWLEN: 13, F: 1]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2672 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http)
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: +++++++++ Incoming Request +++++++++
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: -- State Machine Id: 1
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: GET http:///api/v1/resource/id HTTP/1.1
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: Host: subdomain.domain.com:8080
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: Accept: */*
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1003 (StartRemapRequest)> (http_trans) [1] END HttpTransact::StartRemapRequest
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1005 (StartRemapRequest)> (http_trans) [1] Checking if transaction wants to upgrade
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1012 (StartRemapRequest)> (http_trans) Next action SM_ACTION_API_PRE_REMAP; HttpTransact::PerformRemap
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:7539 (call_transact_and_set_next_state)> (http) [1] State Transition: SM_ACTION_API_READ_REQUEST_HDR -> SM_ACTION_API_PRE_REMAP
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1018 (PerformRemap)> (http_trans) [1] Inside PerformRemap
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1019 (PerformRemap)> (http_trans) Next action SM_ACTION_REMAP_REQUEST; HttpTransact::EndRemapRequest
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:7539 (call_transact_and_set_next_state)> (http) [1] State Transition: SM_ACTION_API_PRE_REMAP -> SM_ACTION_REMAP_REQUEST
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:4211 (do_remap_request)> (http_seq) [1] Remapping request
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1025 (EndRemapRequest)> (http_trans) [1] START HttpTransact::EndRemapRequest
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1031 (EndRemapRequest)> (http_trans) [1] EndRemapRequest host is subdomain.domain.com
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransactHeaders.cc:1151 (add_server_header_to_response)> (http_trans) Adding Server: ATS/9.2.0
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: +++++++++ Proxy's Response 2 +++++++++
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: -- State Machine Id: 1
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found on Accelerator
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: Date: Thu, 18 May 2023 23:17:09 GMT
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: Connection: keep-alive
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: Server: ATS/9.2.0
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1169 (EndRemapRequest)> (http_trans) [1] After Remapping:
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HdrHeap.cc:55 (obj_describe)> (http) HTTP_HEADER 0x2b632e821888: [T: 3, L:   48, OBJFLAGS: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HTTP.cc:550 (http_hdr_describe)> (http) [TYPE: REQ, V: 10001, URL: 0x2b632e821b08, METHOD: "GET", METHOD_LEN: 3, FIELDS: 0x2b632e8218b8]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HdrHeap.cc:55 (obj_describe)> (http) URL 0x2b632e821b08: [T: 2, L:  112, OBJFLAGS: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1723 (url_describe)> (http) [URLTYPE: 1, SWKSIDX: 99,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1725 (url_describe)> (http) #011SCHEME: "http", SCHEME_LEN: 4,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1726 (url_describe)> (http) #011USER: "", USER_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1728 (url_describe)> (http) #011PASSWORD: "", PASSWORD_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1729 (url_describe)> (http) #011HOST: "", HOST_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1731 (url_describe)> (http) #011PORT: "", PORT_LEN: 0, PORT_NUM: 0
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1732 (url_describe)> (http) #011PATH: "api/v1/resource/id", PATH_LEN: 38,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1734 (url_describe)> (http) #011PARAMS: "", PARAMS_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1736 (url_describe)> (http) #011QUERY: "", QUERY_LEN: 0,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <URL.cc:1738 (url_describe)> (http) #011FRAGMENT: "", FRAGMENT_LEN: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HdrHeap.cc:55 (obj_describe)> (http) MIME_HEADER 0x2b632e8218b8: [T: 4, L:  592, OBJFLAGS: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2632 (mime_hdr_describe)> (http) #011[PBITS: 0x0008000001000001, SLACC: 0xFFFFFFF2FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0FFFF, HEADBLK: 0x2b632e8218f8, TAILBLK: 0x2b632e8218f8]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2637 (mime_hdr_describe)> (http) #011[CBITS: 0x00000000, T_MAXAGE: 0, T_SMAXAGE: 0, T_MAXSTALE: 0, T_MINFRESH: 0, PNO$: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HdrHeap.cc:55 (obj_describe)> (http) FIELD_BLOCK 0x2b632e8218f8: [T: 5, L:  528, OBJFLAGS: 0]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2653 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) [FREETOP: 3, NEXTBLK: (nil)]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2657 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) #011SLOT # 0 (0x2b632e821908), LIVE
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2666 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) [N: "User-Agent", N_LEN: 10, N_IDX: 64,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2667 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) V: "curl/7.29.0", V_LEN: 11,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2669 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) NEXTDUP: (nil), RAW: 1, RAWLEN: 25, F: 1]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2672 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http)
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2657 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) #011SLOT # 1 (0x2b632e821928), LIVE
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2666 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) [N: "Host", N_LEN: 4, N_IDX: 30,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2667 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) V: "subdomain.domain.com:8080", V_LEN: 36,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2669 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) NEXTDUP: (nil), RAW: 1, RAWLEN: 44, F: 1]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2672 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http)
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2657 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) #011SLOT # 2 (0x2b632e821948), LIVE
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2666 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) [N: "Accept", N_LEN: 6, N_IDX: 4,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2667 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) V: "*/*", V_LEN: 3,
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2669 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http) NEXTDUP: (nil), RAW: 1, RAWLEN: 13, F: 1]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <MIME.cc:2672 (mime_field_block_describe)> (http)
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1182 (EndRemapRequest)> (http_trans) [1] END HttpTransact::EndRemapRequest
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTransact.cc:1184 (EndRemapRequest)> (http_trans) Next action SM_ACTION_SEND_ERROR_CACHE_NOOP; nullptr
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:7539 (call_transact_and_set_next_state)> (http) [1] State Transition: SM_ACTION_REMAP_REQUEST -> SM_ACTION_SEND_ERROR_CACHE_NOOP
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTunnel.cc:626 (add_producer)> (http_tunnel) [1] adding producer 'internal msg'
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTunnel.cc:681 (add_consumer)> (http_tunnel) [1] adding consumer 'user agent'
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.994] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTunnel.cc:728 (tunnel_run)> (http_tunnel) tunnel_run started, p_arg is provided
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpTunnel.cc:1344 (consumer_handler)> (http_tunnel) [1] consumer_handler [user agent VC_EVENT_WRITE_COMPLETE/TS_EVENT_VCONN_WRITE_COMPLETE]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:3355 (tunnel_handler_ua)> (http) [1] [&HttpSM::tunnel_handler_ua, VC_EVENT_WRITE_COMPLETE/TS_EVENT_VCONN_WRITE_COMPLETE]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:2730 (main_handler)> (http) [1] HTTP_TUNNEL_EVENT_DONE, 2301
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:3025 (tunnel_handler)> (http) [1] [&HttpSM::tunnel_handler, HTTP_TUNNEL_EVENT_DONE]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:8491 (clear)> (http_redirect) [PostDataBuffers::clear]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:7238 (kill_this)> (http_seq) [1] Logging transaction
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <Http1ClientSession.cc:433 (release)> (http_cs) [1] initiating io for next header
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <HttpSM.cc:7284 (kill_this)> (http) [1] deallocating sm
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <Http1ClientSession.cc:374 (state_keep_alive)> (http_cs) [1] [&Http1ClientSession::state_keep_alive, VC_EVENT_EOS/TS_EVENT_VCONN_EOS]
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <Http1ClientSession.cc:265 (do_io_close)> (http_cs) [1] session closed
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: [May 18 23:17:09.995] [ET_NET 13] DEBUG: <Http1ClientSession.cc:75 (destroy)> (http_cs) [1] session destroy
```

This logs means, its reaching to `ATS`, but after that, its not able to go forward.

I have doubt at the above logs where it print as below

```
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: +++++++++ Incoming Request +++++++++
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: -- State Machine Id: 1
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: GET http:///api/v1/resource/id HTTP/1.1
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: Host: subdomain.domain.com:8080
May 18 23:17:10 subdomain.domain.com traffic_manager: Accept: */*
```

It suppose to convert to `http://127.0.0.1:80/api/v1/resource/id`, but it converted to `http:///api/v1/resource/id` and that might be the reason for `404`.

I also tried to check the `map` destination url, `http://127.0.0.1:80` but that is working with `curl` and return `200`.

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:80/api/v1/resource/id -ivks -o /dev/null
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/v1/resource/id HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 18 May 2023 22:54:50 GMT
< P3P: policyref="https://policies.domain.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{ [data not shown]
* Closing connection 0
```

I am using ATS 9.2 (you can see in response headers).

May be I am missing something, not sure what, I read the docs again, but may be missing that configuration piece.